Effect of LiBH4 in AlH3 synthesis
While reading Chemistry of the Element published by A.Earnshaw and N.N Greenwood (page 228), I find this piece of information about synthesis of AlH3 by the reaction between LiAlH4 and AlCl3 in Et2O solvent. The result of the reaction is solvated complex of aluminium trihydride. This could be prevented by the addition of LiBH4. Is the purpose of LiBH4 to produce BH3 which partly forms adduct with the solvent and leaves the product as solid behind?
